# File Reader and implementing it into a Cipher

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am pretty new to `Java`, kind of getting the hang of it, and am working on some code for a Caesar Cipher in my CS class. I have it able to read one line of code from a file and it can `decrypt` and `encrypt` just fine, but I think my teacher wants a full document to be able to be encrypted or decrypted. I know it's possible to have it read the entire document and store it into a string, but how would I go about doing that?

Thanks for any help! Let me know if you need to see my other Class, if you need it for reference.

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;

    public class Project3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cipher caesar = new Cipher();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a filename to encode or decode.");
        String f = input.nextLine();
        String fileName = f;
        String line = null;
        System.out.println("Enter the number of steps to encode or decode the file by: ");
            int i = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
                System.out.println("What would you like to do? Enter [e] to encrypt or press [d] to decrypt.");
                String a = input.nextLine();
                    if(a.equals("e")){
                        String encoded = caesar.useCipher(line,i);
                        caesar.writeToFile(encoded);
                        break;
                        }
                    if(a.equals("d")){
                        String decoded = caesar.useCipher(line,(-i));
                        caesar.writeToFile(decoded);
                        break;
                        }
            }            
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");                  
          }
      }    
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you learn how to use your IDE's debugger so you can step through your code and examine variables at each line.  That is a fundamental skill that you will need in order to become a good developer.  That skill would have allowed you to solve this problem on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Your code already has the loop to process the entire file.

The only problem is the prompt asking what the user wants to do.  THAT part belongs outside (before) the `while` loop.